# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when initialising an NSString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, exc-bad-access

I want to initialise an `NSString` with a character with length of 1, but I get an error. Here's my code:

```
for(int i=0;i<[word length];i++)
    {

        letterMap = [self stringToAscii:[word substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1) ]];
        NSInteger codec = (letterMap + shifter) % 26;
        unichar ch = [self asciiToString:codec];

        NSString * codedLetter = [NSString stringWithCharacters:ch length:[ch length]];

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`unichar` isn't an ObjC object, it's a primitive C type (or typedef) for a single unicode character. You need to call the NSString method (which can take multiple characters in a C-like array) like this:

```
NSString * codedLetter = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&ch length:1];
```

---

(There are two problems in your line of code: first that you're passing the value of a `unichar` as the first argument, instead of a pointer to it, and the second that you're trying to call `-length` on something that's not an ObjC object, or even a pointer. It's blowing up due the latter when it tries to send a message to some random memory address.)